# Not able to replace the view with <ion-nav-view>

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

Not able to replace the view in ionic with . I have menu in form of buttons when I click them the view is not getting replaces.Below is the code I have tried

```
**index.html**
<div class="button-bar">
    <a class="button button-small button-stable button-outline" ui-sref="page1">Page1</a>
    <a class="button button-small button-stable button-outline" ui-sref="page2">Page2</a>
    <a class="button button-small button-stable button-outline" ui-sref="page3">Page3</a>
</div>
<ion-nav-view name="page1"></ion-nav-view>
<ion-nav-view name="page2"></ion-nav-view>
<ion-nav-view name="page3"></ion-nav-view>
```

The js files used to replace the view.In page.controller.js nothing is theres. Just declared with app.controller and nothing is there.

```
**pages.js**
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {    
$stateProvider.state('page1', {
    cache: false,
   parent:'app',           
    views: {
        'page1': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/page1.html',
            controller: 'pages.controller'
        }
    }
}).state('page2', {
    cache: false,
   parent:'app',         
    views: {
        'page2': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/page2.html',
            controller: 'pages.controller'
        }
    }
}).state('page3', {
    cache: false,
   parent:'app',           
    views: {
        'page3': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/page1.html',
            controller: 'pages.controller'
        }
    }
})
});
```

The below are the html pages for the views.

```
page1.html
<ion-view view-title="page1">
<ion-content> 
<div> <h2> Welcome to Page 1</h2> </div>
</ion-view>
</ion-content> 



page2.html
<ion-view view-title="page2">
<ion-content> 
<div> <h2> Welcome to Page 2</h2> </div>
</ion-view>
</ion-content> 



 page3.html 
<ion-view view-title="page3">
<ion-content> 
<div> <h2> Welcome to Page 3</h2> </div>
</ion-view>
</ion-content> 



app.js
var app = angular
    .module(
            'sampleapp',
            [ 'ionic' ]).config(
            function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
                $stateProvider
                        .state('app', {
                            cache : false,
                            url : "/app",
                          abstract:true,
                            templateUrl : "templates/index.html",
                            controller : 'appcontroller'
                        })
```

Kindly, help me understand why the view is not getting replaced.

Comment: Why do you add named view for each page state?

Comment: When I click a particular button and the view related with that state will get activated. So, that the activated view get replaced.

Comment: Where is the parent app state defined?

Comment: @LeandroZubrezki : I have added the app.js

Comment: Why are you defining app in app.js and pages in pages.js? Are you including page.js file? Also you don't need three different views, you just need one and without the names, it will get replaces by the one you select.

Comment: Yes I have included but still my view is not getting replaces

Comment: do any of the pages show? what is the current output?

Answer (score 0):

this is likely because you have 3 different ion-nav-view tags, and each one of them having a separate name, along with each state only replacing its specific tag name.
Which means even if your views are injected, they will overlap (and probably why you're not seeing your views change, as theyre overlapping).

You should change:

index.html

```
<div class="button-bar">
    <a class="button button-small button-stable button-outline" ui-sref="page1">Page1</a>
    <a class="button button-small button-stable button-outline" ui-sref="page2">Page2</a>
    <a class="button button-small button-stable button-outline" ui-sref="page3">Page3</a>
</div>
<ion-nav-view name="page-content"></ion-nav-view>
```

pages.js

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {    
$stateProvider.state('page1', {
    cache: false,
   parent:'app',           
    views: {
        'page-content': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/page1.html',
            controller: 'pages.controller'
        }
    }
}).state('page2', {
    cache: false,
   parent:'app',         
    views: {
        'page-content': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/page2.html',
            controller: 'pages.controller'
        }
    }
}).state('page3', {
    cache: false,
   parent:'app',           
    views: {
        'page-content': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/page1.html',
            controller: 'pages.controller'
        }
    }
})
});
```